# how to identify an invitable friend after he authenticates a app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.4#invites
 , I can get recipient ID of those invitable friends by the api below:
`http://graph.facebook.com/<REQUEST_OBJECT_ID>_<USER_ID>?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN`

(For an invitable friend we only get an request id for each friend like `AVmdFg56QlT-FpSbrAFheEa9aY4d-kFz6uyAIxlt...` instead of his actual user id)

But I found **the recipient ID** I get is different from **the actual user id**. (I compare them after the user authenticates my app.)

My application needs to track those invitable friends in an "activity" object, then when an invitable friend actually authenticate the application, I can add him to the activity that invites him. I want to identify these invitable friends by their ID, since the id is different, so it seems this doesn't work.

Is there any other way to get actually user id? or maybe I should identify them in another way.

The current workaround I come out is identifying them with `REQUEST_OBJECT_ID`.

Comment: That is not how you do it. What you do is you store the request id when the invite is sent. Then when the friends comes to your app you will get the request id and you know how invited him

Comment: @WizKid Thx. That's what I think now.